# Dynamically determine a tensor with which the variable has been initialized in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to dynamically determine a tensor with which the variable has been initialized (NOT an initialized value, but a tensor-initializer!). For example:

```
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(2, 2)))
var2 = tf.Variable(var1.<some method that returns tf.random_normal(shape=(2, 2)>)
```

`Variable.initialized_value()` and `Variable.initial_value` both return the value itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bit an ugly way to do that and I'm posting in case someone else will be interested:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import re

var1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(2, 2)))

shape = var1.initializer.outputs[0].shape
input_ = var1.initializer.node_def.input[1]
tensor_name = (input_ if re.search(r'\d+$', input_) is None
               else '_'.join(input_.split('_')[:-1]))

var2 = tf.Variable(tf.__dict__[tensor_name](shape=shape))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(var1.eval())
    print(var2.eval())
# [[ 0.23845878 -1.1440094 ]
#  [ 0.593299   -1.1108586 ]]
# [[ 1.1235769   1.1481414 ]
#  [ 1.8934027  -0.33171055]]
```

In any case, I'll be glad if someone could provide a cleaner way to do this.

**EDIT**

This works only if the initializing tensors have default names.

**UPDATE**

This is a much better way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(2, 2), mean=1, stddev=3))
var2 = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(var1, var1.graph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(var1.eval())
    print(var2.eval())
# [[1.7009485 0.9412894]
#  [1.0769905 1.3085879]]
# [[ 5.8595214  8.652523 ]
#  [ 1.86671   -3.170361 ]]
```